# jQuery selector with dash and spaces of classname

Tags: jquery

I know that if I have a class name (with spaces), e.g.

```
my classname
```

I can create a class selector with:

```
.my.classname
```

However, how can I create a class selector If I have dashes between spaces like this:

```
My - Classname and Others
```

Or this:

```
My - Clasname
```

Thanks for the tips.

Comment: But why do you create such classNames?

Comment: For a specific application, that's from a short title. Is it possible? Thanks.

Comment: Your first selector selects the last example, you don't have to use all the class names in the selector.

Comment: Why not simply convert titles `My - Classname` to `my.classname`

Comment: I'm not entirely sure I understand the question. What do you mean by "how can I create a class selector"? This may help as well - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/448981/what-characters-are-valid-in-css-class-names

Comment: (1:) What is `and Others` ? (2:) What is *"short titles"* ? (3:) again, why you need it? (4:) can we see some example?

Comment: I'm fairly sure the whole problem here stems from one misunderstanding: "I know that if I have a class name (with spaces), e.g. my classname". No, you do not have a class name of 'my classname", you have an element with two classes - 'my', and 'classname'. `.my.classname` in css selects all elements who have both the class 'my' and the class 'classname', so it would also select an element for which the class attribute is "my class is totally not classname".

Comment: why you need such names ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not simply to convert titles `My - Classname` to `.my.classname`

<kbd>**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsbin.com/eratuk/1/edit)**</kbd>

```
var title   = "Properties Listing - 3 Per Page";
var toClass = '.'+ title.replace(/-/g, '').replace(/\s{1,}/g, '.').toLowerCase() ;

alert(toClass); // .properties.listing.3.per.page
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no difference from the first case except that your element will have 3 class: `My` , `-` and `Classname`. So you just need to do the same selector:

```
$(".my.-.classname")
```

Comment: I even have complex class names like Properties Listing - 3 Per Page so the selector would be: .Properties.Listing.-.3.Per.Page   ,I tried running this and it does not work.

Comment: @roXon I think space is only valid class when you have another class name for that element http://jsfiddle.net/TnBLf/

Comment: @CodexMeridian well how come your class name like that? But it's still work http://jsfiddle.net/TnBLf/1/

Comment: @user1479606 `space` is not a class name, it is considered as a separator. check the [html5](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/elements.html#classes) spec

Comment: @ArunPJohny sorry I mean dash, just a typo

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [attribute selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) for this purpose.

```
$('[class="My - Clasname"]')
```

Note: `My - Classname and Others` is not a single class it is a mix of 5 classes `My`,  `-`, `Classname`, `and` and `Others`.

Comment: ...where `-` (as standalone) is not a valid className, therefore the answer is valid(?)

Comment: @roXon sorry missed that point, any way I think the selector will work

Comment: I think it will, but in any case... should be avoided as not semantic, errata prone and all the possible terms you can invent :)

Comment: @roXon yes of course, I was going through [html4](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/global.html#adef-class) and [html5](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/elements.html#classes) but no where I found `-` is a invalid class name. Can you point me to some spec doc regarding this

Comment: and also read this: [W3Standards/allowed/classnames-part2](http://jsfiddle.net/Tfe8F/1/) ;) Now read my first comment

Comment: @roXon it is a implementation right, or is it specified somewhere in the w3c spec doc

Comment: It was just a joke, but I'm surprised how we're searching for written proof for something that clearly does not work, in any case: http://www.w3.org/QA/Tips/goodclassnames